# Using array.push to build JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Can't figure this out.

```
var states = [];
for(var i = 0; i<transactions.length; i++){

  var state = {name: transactions[i].name, amount: transactions[i].amount}
  console.log(state)
  states.push[state];
 console.log(states)
}
```

Just trying to put together a an array of abbreviated transactions data as "states".

My printed console looks like:

```
{ name: 'United Airlines', amount: -500 }
[]
{ name: 'McDonald\'s', amount: 12 }
[]
{ name: 'Starbucks', amount: 4.33 }
[]
{ name: 'SparkFun', amount: 89.4 }
[]
{ name: 'INTRST PYMNT', amount: -4.22 }
[]  <<<<<nothing in my states array?
```

Comment: states.push(state);

Comment: You're using the wrong type of brackets for push there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` is a function. Call it with `()`.

By using `[]`, you're trying to access a property of the push object.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Should've seen that.